# How to append a string value in the column value in Copy Activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

In below copy activity screen shot , i am trying to create a new column(PartitionKey) whose value is same as DocType column. I would also like to insert one string value along with Doctype value. something like concat("recoding",$.Doctype) as value of PartitionKey. I am unable to do so and would like to know if this is possible to do.

I want this because I get error for some items where DocType key is not present. and I would like to avoid that.

The error message i get is below and I am not sure for which item this error occurs as there are thousands of items getting copied.

> ErrorCode=DuplicateColumnNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
> name '$.DocType' to be duplicated is not found in the source data.
> Please check the source column name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this cannot be done via a Copy Data Activity. Unless you are using a DB as the Source. If you are using a DB as the source then you could use custom SQL to derive fields.

The other option is to use a Data Flow and you can create derived fields.

See this link for explanations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

[image: Example using Expression]

Comment: Whats DB? database? I cant use mapping data flow because in data flow the schema is mismatched and also it do not take all the values if the values does not appear in sample documents

Comment: Yes DB= Database. If you have an Azure SQL Database or really any other database, you can define whatever fields you would like, but it seems you are not using a Database... if you wanted though, you could load your file/data to an Azure SQLDB as a sort of staging area, then do a copy activity from the Azure SQLDB to whatever sink you want, doing this you can define derived columns in the SQL. If you want to see an example of this I can edit my answer, but only if you are interested. Let me know.

Comment: I am using Cosmos Db SQL API as my source database and in Copy activity you can add an extra column based on another existing column but you cant append any concat any string value to it. another solution is to use mapping data flow and there I can use derived columns but in this case i dont get all my columns in the sink because data flow only take columns which comes in first sample list. Please let me know if you have any other approach

Comment: It cannot be done in Copy Activity unless you use a database source, (not a DB API... unless you derive your columns there, not sure if that's possible)